# Knockout SelectedOptions with non-multi select

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

Good day,

I have a scenario with an object similar to this:

```
{
 options: [{},{},{}], //array of objects
 selected: [], //array of selected objects
 multiselect: false,  //determine if one or multiple values should be selectable
}
```

I want to bind this object to a select element in a template, as follows:

```
<select data-bind="selectedOptions: selected, options: options, attr: { multiple: multiselect }"></select>
```

My hope here was, even if it's a single item select list, it'd push the value into the selected array.
Unfortunately, it appears selectedOptions on a non-multi select list doesn't default a value into the array:

Here's a fiddle showing what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/15444/

Note that the first displayed value is 0 until an option on the first select list is selected.

Is it possible to change this functionality directly?  I'd prefer not to have to push the first value into the array with other javascript (there are some cases where I may not render a selection object at all, and thus would have to use extensive logic).
What about a way to make value: push/pop on an array instead?

Hoping there's something simple before I have to write a custom binding or some sort.

Comment: am i right that you want to push every selected value in selectedOption?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subscribe to keep "selected"  in sync of svalue.
http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/15468/

```
<div>
  <select data-bind="value: svalue, options: options"></select>
  <br />
  Items in Array: <div data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(selectedOptions())"></div>
  Selected Value: <div data-bind="text: svalue"></div>
</div>

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.options = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  this.selectedOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.svalue = ko.observable();
  this.count = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.selectedOptions().length;
  }, this);

  this.svalue.subscribe(function(new_v) {
    if (new_v) self.selectedOptions([new_v]);
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Thank you for tanking the time to write a response :)
Making the select multiselect or not wasn't the issue however.  It was rather getting the value to still store the default selection into the selectedOptions list, when the list is non-multiselect.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom binding to handle the scenario

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectedValues = {
//support an array with single value, for making my life easier.
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var arraystore = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    if ($.type(arraystore) != 'array')
        throw ('Custom Binding -- Wrong data type used with this binding');
    var val = ko.observable(arraystore[0]);
    val.subscribe(function (newval) {
        arraystore.length = 0;
        arraystore.push(newval);
    });
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: val });
}
```

}

then I switch off between two templates.  A lot of extra work unfortunately :(